# Linear Regression in R: "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object not found"

Tags: r, regression

I'm trying to do a simple least-squares regression in R and have been getting errors constantly. This is really frustrating, can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

First I attach the dataset (17 variables, 440 observations, each observation on a single line, no column titles). Here, I get a "masked" error. From what I've read, the "masked" error happens when objects overlap. However here I am not using any packages but the default, and I loaded a new workspace image before this. Not sure what this error refers to?

```
> cdi=read.table("APPENC02.txt", header=FALSE)
> attach(cdi)
The following objects are masked from cdi (position 3):

    V1, V10, V11, V12, V13, V14, V15, V16, V17, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6, V7, V8, V9
```

Next, since the data set does not come with headings, I use the `colnames()` command to add column names, then check my work with the `head()` command:

```
colnames(cdi)<- c("IDnmbr","Countynm","Stateabv","LandArea","totpop","youngpct","oldpct","actphy","hspbed","srscrime","hsgrad","BAgrad","povpct","unempct","pcincome","totincome","georegion")
> head(cdi)
  IDnmbr    Countynm Stateabv LandArea  totpop youngpct oldpct actphy hspbed srscrime hsgrad BAgrad povpct unempct pcincome totincome georegion
1      1 Los_Angeles       CA     4060 8863164     32.1    9.7  23677  27700   688936   70.0   22.3   11.6     8.0    20786    184230         4
2      2        Cook       IL      946 5105067     29.2   12.4  15153  21550   436936   73.4   22.8   11    etcetc(manually truncated)
```

Now the most annoying part: I can't get the lm() function to work!

```
> model1=lm(actphy~totpop)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'actphy' not found
```

It's not a upper/lowercase issue, and i've tried `"actphy"` and `actphy`. What gives?

Also, the manual i'm following suggests using the `attach()` function but I've read a few posts discouraging it. What would be a better solution in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: You simply need to use `lm(actphy ~ totpop, data = cdi)` so that `lm` knows where to find the variables in the formula (they are not in the global environment/workspace, they are in the data frame you created).  By the way, for troubleshooting it is helpful to clean out your workspace before trying things, you can use `rm(list = ls())`.  `ls()` tells you what variables are in your workspace at any time.

Comment: This is actually an excellent example of why `attach` is terrible, and it's use at the beginning of an R tutorial is a good reason to run the other direction, fast.

Comment: ...it's not just "a few posts" that warn about it's use, read the documentation at `?attach`! If the docs are warning you to avoid it, beware folks writing "tutorials" recommending it.

Comment: Yes, but this is *quite* a mouthful: *In interactive use, ‘with’ is usually preferable to the use of ‘attach’/‘detach’, unless when ‘what’ is ‘save()’-produced file in which case ‘attach()’ is a (safety) wrapper for ‘load()’.*

Comment: thanks @bryanhanson and joran! do you guys have an answer to the first portion too (the source of my "object not found" and "masked" errors)?

Comment: The object not found results from `actphy` not being on the search path, per my comment.  The masking means you had objects in your workspace called `V1...Vn` already.  That's why I suggested using `ls()` to see what's there already.  Another really helpful thing to know is `str(some_object)` which shows you how it is stored.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @joran comments, `attach` is a dangerous thing. Just see, for example, this simple set of code:

```
> x <- 2:1
> d <- data.frame(x=1:2, y=3:4)
> lm(y~x)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'y' not found
> lm(y~x, data=d)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = d)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
          2            1  

> attach(d)
The following object is masked _by_ .GlobalEnv:

    x

> lm(y~x, data=d)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = d)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
          2            1  

> lm(y~x)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
          5           -1
```

Using `attach` puts the data.frame on the search path, which allows you to cheat in `lm` by not specifying a `data` argument. However, this means that if there are objects in your global environment that have names conflicting with objects in your data.frame, weird stuff can happen, like in the last two results in the code shown above.