# Linear Regression in R: error in eval(expr, envr, enclos) : object not found

Tags: r, regression, economics

I've been searching for a solution for several days, but nothing has worked yet.  I'm trying to run a very basic linear regression on college costs and graduate earnings using the [College Scorecard data](https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/data/).

Here's how I read the data:

```
library(readr)

CollegeScorecard2015 <- read_csv("~/Downloads/CollegeScorecard2015.csv", na = "null")

View(CollegeScorecard2015)
```

Everything looks good.  Then I try to run the regression, referencing the variables from College Scorecard's "Data Dictionary."  If I use either one of these:

`regmod = lm(MN_EARN_WNE_P10~NPT4_PUB)`

or

`regmod = lm(MN_EARN_WNE_P10$CollegeScorecard2015~NPT4_PUB$CollegeScorecard2015)`

then I get this message:

`Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'MN_EARN_WNE_P10' not found`

and, after the summary:

`In summary.lm(regmod) : essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable`

If I use this instead, as suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752999/linear-regression-in-r-error-in-evalexpr-envir-enclos-object-not-found):

`regmod = lm(MN_EARN_WNE_P10 ~ NPT4_PUB, data = CollegeScorecard2015)`

then I get the following:

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'
In addition: Warning message:
In model.response(mf, "numeric") : NAs introduced by coercion
```

and the same message after the summary as above.

Might this be a problem with the data set?  I'm not sure what it would be though, as I can see the data is right there.  The variables match with the Data Dictionary.  Not quire sure what to do.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Make sure your options are set correctly. Try `options(na.action=na.omit)`. If this doesn't work try looking at the data make sure values are numeric. If nothing else you should be able to manually clean up the data.

Comment: Seems like your outcome variable is a character. Check the class of MN_EARN_WNE_P10

Comment: What @CCurtis said.

Comment: In the MN_EARN_WNE_P10 column, most entries are numerical.  Some say "NULL" and some say "PrivacySuppressed."  I changed the code to: 

`CollegeScorecard2015 <- read_csv("~/Downloads/CollegeScorecard2015.csv", na = "NULL", "PrivacySuppressed")` 

and used `options(na.action=na.omit)` as @CCurtis suggested.  Still getting the same errors.  The `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` command doesn't seem to be doing anything, either (it comes back as unused).